# Assigning multiple iterables in a for loop

Tags: python

I'm writing a file uploader with two attributes for a user uploading 1 to 3 files. So far I've come up with:

```
for (file, text, url) in zip(request.FILES, request.POST['portfolio-text'], request.POST['portfolio-url']):
    new_file = File.objects.create(user=request.user, file=request.FILES[file], text=text, url=url)
```

The issue that arises with this is `request.POST['portfolio-text']` and  `request.POST['portfolio-url']` are strings. With `zip` the two strings are iterated on a character by character basis. So if I have one file with the text `u'foo'` and the url `u'www.baz.com'` the first iteration will look like this:

```
file: <file>
text: u'f'
url: u'w'
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will work:

```
for (file, text, url) in zip(request.FILES, [request.POST['portfolio-text']], [request.POST['portfolio-url']]):
    new_file = File.objects.create(user=request.user, file=request.FILES[file], text=text, url=url)
```